# CakePHP automatically remove associated items

Tags: database, cakephp, associations

this may be a rookie question for CakePHP but here it goes

I design 3 models with associations:

'Client' hasMany 'Invoice' hasMany 'Item'

So when we do a read from Client, it will automatically grab related Invoices.

What if we try to delete a Client, is there a way so that CakePHP will automatically delete all related entries in 'Invoice' and subsequently all related entries in 'Item' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if the association is declared as `dependent`.
See http://book.cakephp.org/view/1043/hasMany.